# How to override form field in Django function based view?

Tags: python, django, forms

I like to use a form in a function based view but I like to override the `kategoria` select field to show only the objects that related to the user.

models.py

```
class Blog_poszt(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="blog_szerzo")
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    cim = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    cim_slug = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    szoveg = models.CharField(max_length=10000, null=True, blank=True)
    kategoria = models.ForeignKey('Blog_kategoriak', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    kep = models.FileField(upload_to="blog/", null=True, blank=True)

class Blog_kategoriak(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="kategoria_szerzo")
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    kategoria = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

forms.py

```
class UjBlogposztForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Blog_poszt
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('user',)
```

views.py

```
def blog_poszt(request):

    form = UjBlogposztForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid:
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
```

html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %} 
        {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Mentés</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

```py
def blog_poszt(request):
    ... 
    form = UjBlogposztForm()
    form.fields["kategoria"].queryset = Blog_kategoriak.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    context = {"form": form}
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `__init__` method of the form.

Try this as below:

#### forms.py

```
from django import forms

class UjBlogposztForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Blog_poszt
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('user',) 

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(UjBlogposztForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user:
            self.fields['kategoria'].queryset = Blog_kategoriak.objects.filter(user=user)
```

#### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def blog_poszt(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UjBlogposztForm(request.POST, request.FILES, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            # Redirect to a success page or handle as needed
    else:
        form = UjBlogposztForm(user=request.user)

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', context)
```

The `__init__` method of `UjBlogposztForm` is modified to accept the user argument, which is used to filter the your model `kategoria` field's queryset to only show categories related to that user. In the view file, the current user `(request.user)` is passed to the form upon instantiation, ensuring that the `kategoria` field is populated with choices relevant only to the current user.